# Debian suddenly lost graphical interface

Tags: linux, debian, virtualbox

My vm runs on a debian os and it has worked well until suddenly the window keeps flashing. I turned it down and then when I came back and re-logged in, the graphical interface is gone. Now the logging in is shown as :

[image: No-graphical-interface]

Info :

```
debian : debian-10.7.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1.iso for Debian ISO image 
host : Win 10 
virtualbox : VirtualBox 6.1.16
```

Any idea what happened and how to fix this ?

PS: it seems that the case happens when it's going to idle mode : The first time I install the system, and log in, everything is fine. Then when I didn't touch it for a while, it went to idle mode and crashed

PS2 : if I logged in in the no-GUI mode, and use command `startx`, I will enter into the graphical interface, but with no response at all, except the mouse could move.

PS3 : I also notice that in start-up, there seems to be some `sensor not found error`[image]

PS3 : From dmesg, I found a re-mounted error, not sure if it's related :

```
[    1.844082] systemd-udevd[456]: link_config: autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable.
[    1.900356] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
[    1.928662] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.928663] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.940952] input: VirtualBox USB Tablet as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:80EE:0021.0001/input/input8
[    1.941111] hid-generic 0003:80EE:0021.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [VirtualBox USB Tablet] on usb-0000:00:06.0-1/input0
[    2.997742] snd_intel8x0 0000:00:05.0: white list rate for 1028:0177 is 48000
[    3.257158] Adding 998396k swap on /dev/sda5.  Priority:-2 extents:1 across:998396k FS
[    3.283602] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
```

PS4 : log message from `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`

```
[     7.389] 
X.Org X Server 1.20.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[     7.389] Build Operating System: Linux 4.19.0-12-amd64 x86_64 Debian
[     7.389] Current Operating System: Linux vandys 4.19.0-13-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.160-2 (2020-11-28) x86_64
[     7.389] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-13-amd64 root=UUID=211eb506-9c5c-4d3b-9d63-2641d5b6e796 ro quiet
[     7.389] Build Date: 01 December 2020  05:59:57PM
[     7.389] xorg-server 2:1.20.4-1+deb10u2 (https://www.debian.org/support) 
[     7.389] Current version of pixman: 0.36.0
[     7.389]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[     7.389] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[     7.389] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sun Dec 27 18:29:56 2020
[     7.393] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[     7.395] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[     7.395] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[     7.395] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[     7.395] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[     7.396] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[     7.396] (==) Automatically adding devices
[     7.396] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[     7.396] (==) Automatically adding GPU devices
[     7.396] (==) Max clients allowed: 256, resource mask: 0x1fffff
[     7.399] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[     7.399]    Entry deleted from font path.
[     7.403] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi,
    built-ins
[     7.403] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[     7.403] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[     7.403] (II) Loader magic: 0x55be10576e20
[     7.403] (II) Module ABI versions:
[     7.403]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[     7.403]    X.Org Video Driver: 24.0
[     7.403]    X.Org XInput driver : 24.1
[     7.403]    X.Org Server Extension : 10.0
[     7.404] (++) using VT number 7

[     7.404] (II) systemd-logind: logind integration requires -keeptty and -keeptty was not provided, disabling logind integration
[     7.404] (II) xfree86: Adding drm device (/dev/dri/card0)
[     7.407] (--) PCI:*(0@0:2:0) 15ad:0405:15ad:0405 rev 0, Mem @ 0xe0000000/16777216, 0xf0000000/2097152, I/O @ 0x0000d010/16, BIOS @ 0x????????/131072
[     7.407] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[     7.407] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[     7.415] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.415]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.415]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 10.0
[     7.415] (==) Matched vmware as autoconfigured driver 0
[     7.415] (==) Matched modesetting as autoconfigured driver 1
[     7.415] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 2
[     7.415] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 3
[     7.415] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[     7.415] (II) LoadModule: "vmware"
[     7.415] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vmware_drv.so
[     7.495] (II) Module vmware: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.495]    compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 13.3.0
[     7.495]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     7.495]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     7.495] (II) LoadModule: "modesetting"
[     7.495] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/modesetting_drv.so
[     7.496] (II) Module modesetting: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.496]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.20.4
[     7.496]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     7.496]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     7.496] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[     7.496] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[     7.496] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.496]    compiled for 1.20.0, module version = 0.5.0
[     7.496]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     7.496]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     7.496] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[     7.496] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[     7.497] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.497]    compiled for 1.20.1, module version = 2.4.0
[     7.497]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[     7.497]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     7.497] (II) vmware: driver for VMware SVGA: vmware0405, vmware0710
[     7.497] (II) modesetting: Driver for Modesetting Kernel Drivers: kms
[     7.497] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[     7.497] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[     7.500] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for modesetting
[     7.500] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[     7.500] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[     7.500] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[     7.500] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[     7.501] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.501]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.0.2
[     7.501]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 24.0
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[     7.501] (--) vmware(0): DRM driver version is 2.15.0
[     7.501] (==) vmware(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[     7.501] (==) vmware(0): RGB weight 888
[     7.501] (==) vmware(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[     7.501] (--) vmware(0): Min width 1, Max Width 8192.
[     7.501] (--) vmware(0): Min height 1, Max Height 8192.
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual1 has no monitor section
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual2 has no monitor section
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual3 has no monitor section
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual4 has no monitor section
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual5 has no monitor section
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual6 has no monitor section
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual7 has no monitor section
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual8 has no monitor section
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Printing probed modes for output Virtual1
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.0   42.75  800 850 900 950  600 650 700 750 -hsync +vsync (45.0 kHz eP)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "2560x1600"x60.0  348.50  2560 2752 3032 3504  1600 1603 1609 1658 -hsync +vsync (99.5 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1920x1440"x60.0  234.00  1920 2048 2256 2600  1440 1441 1444 1500 -hsync +vsync (90.0 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1856x1392"x60.0  218.25  1856 1952 2176 2528  1392 1393 1396 1439 -hsync +vsync (86.3 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1792x1344"x60.0  204.75  1792 1920 2120 2448  1344 1345 1348 1394 -hsync +vsync (83.6 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1920x1200"x59.9  193.25  1920 2056 2256 2592  1200 1203 1209 1245 -hsync +vsync (74.6 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x60.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x60.0  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1400x1050"x60.0  121.75  1400 1488 1632 1864  1050 1053 1057 1089 -hsync +vsync (65.3 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x60.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1440x900"x59.9  106.50  1440 1520 1672 1904  900 903 909 934 -hsync +vsync (55.9 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x960"x60.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1360x768"x60.0   85.50  1360 1424 1536 1792  768 771 777 795 +hsync +vsync (47.7 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x800"x59.8   83.50  1280 1352 1480 1680  800 803 809 831 +hsync -vsync (49.7 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1152x864"x75.0  108.00  1152 1216 1344 1600  864 865 868 900 +hsync +vsync (67.5 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1280x768"x59.9   79.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  768 771 778 798 -hsync +vsync (47.8 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "1024x768"x60.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "800x600"x60.3   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): Modeline "640x480"x59.9   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 489 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual2
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual3
[     7.501] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual4
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual5
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual6
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual7
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): EDID for output Virtual8
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual1 connected
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual2 disconnected
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual3 disconnected
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual4 disconnected
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual5 disconnected
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual6 disconnected
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual7 disconnected
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual8 disconnected
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): Using exact sizes for initial modes
[     7.502] (II) vmware(0): Output Virtual1 using initial mode 800x600 +0+0
[     7.502] (==) vmware(0): DPI set to (96, 96)
[     7.502] (==) vmware(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[     7.502] (II) Loading sub module "fb"
[     7.502] (II) LoadModule: "fb"
[     7.502] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfb.so
[     7.505] (II) Module fb: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.505]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 1.0.0
[     7.505]    ABI class: X.Org ANSI C Emulation, version 0.4
[     7.505] (II) Loading sub module "dri2"
[     7.505] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[     7.505] (II) Module "dri2" already built-in
[     7.505] (II) Loading sub module "dri3"
[     7.505] (II) LoadModule: "dri3"
[     7.505] (II) Module "dri3" already built-in
[     7.505] (II) UnloadModule: "modesetting"
[     7.505] (II) Unloading modesetting
[     7.505] (II) UnloadModule: "fbdev"
[     7.505] (II) Unloading fbdev
[     7.505] (II) UnloadSubModule: "fbdevhw"
[     7.505] (II) Unloading fbdevhw
[     7.505] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[     7.505] (II) Unloading vesa
[     7.510] (II) vmware(0): Initialized VMWARE_CTRL extension version 0.2
[     7.514] (WW) vmware(0): Failed to initialize Gallium3D Xa. No render acceleration available.
[     7.514] (WW) vmware(0): Skipped initialization of direct rendering due to lack of render acceleration.
[     7.514] (--) vmware(0): Render acceleration is disabled.
[     7.514] (==) vmware(0): Rendercheck mode is disabled.
[     7.514] (--) vmware(0): Direct rendering (DRI2 3D) is disabled.
[     7.514] (--) vmware(0): Direct rendering (DRI3 3D) is disabled.
[     7.514] (==) vmware(0): Backing store enabled
[     7.514] (==) vmware(0): Silken mouse enabled
[     7.515] (==) vmware(0): DPMS enabled
[     7.515] (II) vmware(0): No 3D acceleration. Not setting up textured video.
[     7.515] (WW) vmware(0): Disabling Xv because no adaptors could be initialized.
[     7.515] (II) Initializing extension Generic Event Extension
[     7.516] (II) Initializing extension SHAPE
[     7.516] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SHM
[     7.516] (II) Initializing extension XInputExtension
[     7.516] (II) Initializing extension XTEST
[     7.516] (II) Initializing extension BIG-REQUESTS
[     7.516] (II) Initializing extension SYNC
[     7.516] (II) Initializing extension XKEYBOARD
[     7.516] (II) Initializing extension XC-MISC
[     7.517] (II) Initializing extension SECURITY
[     7.517] (II) Initializing extension XFIXES
[     7.517] (II) Initializing extension RENDER
[     7.517] (II) Initializing extension RANDR
[     7.517] (II) Initializing extension COMPOSITE
[     7.517] (II) Initializing extension DAMAGE
[     7.517] (II) Initializing extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[     7.517] (II) Initializing extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[     7.517] (II) Initializing extension RECORD
[     7.517] (II) Initializing extension DPMS
[     7.517] (II) Initializing extension Present
[     7.517] (II) Initializing extension DRI3
[     7.517] (II) Initializing extension X-Resource
[     7.518] (II) Initializing extension XVideo
[     7.518] (II) Initializing extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[     7.518] (II) Initializing extension SELinux
[     7.518] (II) SELinux: Disabled on system
[     7.518] (II) Initializing extension GLX
[     7.518] (II) AIGLX: Screen 0 is not DRI2 capable
[     7.545] (II) IGLX: Loaded and initialized swrast
[     7.545] (II) GLX: Initialized DRISWRAST GL provider for screen 0
[     7.545] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[     7.545] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DGA
[     7.545] (II) Initializing extension XFree86-DRI
[     7.545] (II) Initializing extension DRI2
[     7.548] (II) vmware(0): Setting screen physical size to 211 x 158
[     7.594] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Power Button (/dev/input/event1)
[     7.594] (**) Power Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     7.594] (II) LoadModule: "libinput"
[     7.594] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/input/libinput_drv.so
[     7.599] (II) Module libinput: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[     7.599]    compiled for 1.20.4, module version = 0.28.2
[     7.599]    Module class: X.Org XInput Driver
[     7.599]    ABI class: X.Org XInput driver, version 24.1
[     7.599] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[     7.599] (**) Power Button: always reports core events
[     7.599] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event1"
[     7.600] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     7.606] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     7.606] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[     7.606] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[     7.606] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input2/event1"
[     7.606] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Power Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 6)
[     7.606] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     7.606] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     7.607] (II) event1  - Power Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     7.607] (II) event1  - Power Button: device is a keyboard
[     7.607] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Sleep Button (/dev/input/event2)
[     7.607] (**) Sleep Button: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     7.607] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[     7.607] (**) Sleep Button: always reports core events
[     7.607] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event2"
[     7.607] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     7.612] (II) event2  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     7.612] (II) event2  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[     7.612] (II) event2  - Sleep Button: device removed
[     7.612] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSLPBN:00/input/input3/event2"
[     7.612] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Sleep Button" (type: KEYBOARD, id 7)
[     7.612] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     7.612] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     7.613] (II) event2  - Sleep Button: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     7.613] (II) event2  - Sleep Button: device is a keyboard
[     7.613] (II) config/udev: Adding input device Video Bus (/dev/input/event3)
[     7.613] (**) Video Bus: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     7.613] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[     7.613] (**) Video Bus: always reports core events
[     7.613] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event3"
[     7.613] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     7.613] (II) event3  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     7.613] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[     7.613] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device removed
[     7.614] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A03:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input4/event3"
[     7.614] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "Video Bus" (type: KEYBOARD, id 8)
[     7.614] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     7.614] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     7.614] (II) event3  - Video Bus: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     7.614] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device is a keyboard
[     7.615] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualBox mouse integration (/dev/input/event6)
[     7.615] (**) VirtualBox mouse integration: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[     7.615] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'VirtualBox mouse integration'
[     7.615] (**) VirtualBox mouse integration: always reports core events
[     7.615] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event6"
[     7.615] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     7.615] (II) event6  - VirtualBox mouse integration: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[     7.615] (II) event6  - VirtualBox mouse integration: device is a pointer
[     7.615] (II) event6  - VirtualBox mouse integration: device removed
[     7.615] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:04.0/input/input7/event6"
[     7.615] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "VirtualBox mouse integration" (type: MOUSE, id 9)
[     7.615] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[     7.615] (**) VirtualBox mouse integration: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[     7.615] (**) VirtualBox mouse integration: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     7.615] (**) VirtualBox mouse integration: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     7.616] (II) event6  - VirtualBox mouse integration: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[     7.616] (II) event6  - VirtualBox mouse integration: device is a pointer
[     7.616] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualBox mouse integration (/dev/input/js0)
[     7.616] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     7.616] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     7.617] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualBox USB Tablet (/dev/input/event7)
[     7.617] (**) VirtualBox USB Tablet: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[     7.617] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'VirtualBox USB Tablet'
[     7.617] (**) VirtualBox USB Tablet: always reports core events
[     7.617] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[     7.617] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     7.678] (II) event7  - VirtualBox USB Tablet: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[     7.678] (II) event7  - VirtualBox USB Tablet: device is a pointer
[     7.678] (II) event7  - VirtualBox USB Tablet: device removed
[     7.684] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:80EE:0021.0001/input/input8/event7"
[     7.684] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "VirtualBox USB Tablet" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[     7.684] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[     7.684] (**) VirtualBox USB Tablet: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[     7.684] (**) VirtualBox USB Tablet: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     7.684] (**) VirtualBox USB Tablet: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     7.746] (II) event7  - VirtualBox USB Tablet: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[     7.746] (II) event7  - VirtualBox USB Tablet: device is a pointer
[     7.747] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualBox USB Tablet (/dev/input/js1)
[     7.747] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     7.747] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     7.747] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualBox USB Tablet (/dev/input/mouse1)
[     7.747] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     7.747] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     7.748] (II) config/udev: Adding input device AT Translated Set 2 keyboard (/dev/input/event0)
[     7.748] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: Applying InputClass "libinput keyboard catchall"
[     7.748] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[     7.748] (**) AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: always reports core events
[     7.748] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event0"
[     7.748] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     7.748] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     7.748] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[     7.748] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[     7.748] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input0/event0"
[     7.748] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard" (type: KEYBOARD, id 11)
[     7.748] (**) Option "xkb_model" "pc105"
[     7.748] (**) Option "xkb_layout" "us"
[     7.749] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: is tagged by udev as: Keyboard
[     7.749] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device is a keyboard
[     7.750] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse (/dev/input/event4)
[     7.750] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[     7.750] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse'
[     7.750] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: always reports core events
[     7.750] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event4"
[     7.750] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[     7.750] (II) event4  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[     7.750] (II) event4  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: device is a pointer
[     7.750] (II) event4  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: device removed
[     7.750] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input5/event4"
[     7.750] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse" (type: MOUSE, id 12)
[     7.751] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[     7.751] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[     7.751] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[     7.751] (**) ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[     7.751] (II) event4  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[     7.751] (II) event4  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: device is a pointer
[     7.751] (II) config/udev: Adding input device ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse (/dev/input/mouse0)
[     7.751] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     7.751] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[     7.752] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PC Speaker (/dev/input/event5)
[     7.752] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[     7.752] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[    32.450] (EE) No surface to present from.
[   675.003] (II) event1  - Power Button: device removed
[   675.004] (II) event2  - Sleep Button: device removed
[   675.005] (II) event3  - Video Bus: device removed
[   675.005] (II) event6  - VirtualBox mouse integration: device removed
[   675.006] (II) event7  - VirtualBox USB Tablet: device removed
[   675.019] (II) event0  - AT Translated Set 2 keyboard: device removed
[   675.020] (II) event4  - ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse: device removed
[   707.817] (II) config/udev: removing device VirtualBox USB Tablet
[   707.818] (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
[   708.840] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualBox USB Tablet (/dev/input/js1)
[   708.840] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   708.840] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   708.851] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualBox USB Tablet (/dev/input/mouse1)
[   708.851] (II) No input driver specified, ignoring this device.
[   708.851] (II) This device may have been added with another device file.
[   708.986] (II) config/udev: Adding input device VirtualBox USB Tablet (/dev/input/event7)
[   708.986] (**) VirtualBox USB Tablet: Applying InputClass "libinput pointer catchall"
[   708.986] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'VirtualBox USB Tablet'
[   708.986] (**) VirtualBox USB Tablet: always reports core events
[   708.986] (**) Option "Device" "/dev/input/event7"
[   708.986] (**) Option "_source" "server/udev"
[   709.046] (II) event7  - VirtualBox USB Tablet: is tagged by udev as: Mouse
[   709.046] (II) event7  - VirtualBox USB Tablet: device is a pointer
[   709.047] (II) event7  - VirtualBox USB Tablet: device removed
[   709.050] (**) Option "config_info" "udev:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/0003:80EE:0021.0002/input/input9/event7"
[   709.050] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "VirtualBox USB Tablet" (type: MOUSE, id 10)
[   709.051] (**) Option "AccelerationScheme" "none"
[   709.051] (**) VirtualBox USB Tablet: (accel) selected scheme none/0
[   709.051] (**) VirtualBox USB Tablet: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[   709.051] (**) VirtualBox USB Tablet: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
```

Update : It seems there is something wrong with `debian-10.7.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1`, not sure whether it's some known bug for debian community, but after I changed to `debian-10.5.0-amd64-xfce-CD-1`, it seems to work well so far.

Comment: You need to debug this, nobody has a crystal ball that can show us what goes wrong inside your VM. (And please don't post screenshots, they are not searchable; copy-and-paste text). So: log into your VM (apparently you can still do that), work through the startup `dmesg`, `/var/log/Xorg.log.0` (if you are using X), and `/var/log/syslog*` to see if you can find the place where the GUI bails out. Then correct it.

Comment: I search through dmesg and found `EXT4-fs (sda-1):remounted. Opts:errors=remount-ro `. Is it because of the error in mounting some e.g., Guest Additions ISO ?

Comment: I have no idea without seeing dmesg, you are leaving out all the information that would help me to find out (do you really think people own a crystal ball? Debugging is not black magic). Look **above** that line in dmesg. What is the **reason** it decides to remount? And yes, remounting r/o may affect e.g. the start of X.

Comment: I second what dirkt notes, there's no information. Try: cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | tail -n 40 and look for failure messages. Usually logging in and finding a blinking cursor means the graphics driver load failed. Note that this is very unlikely to be a vm related issue, that's probably a red herring, unless you were using drivers from windows or something odd like that. There's no information however that can be used to offer support that I can see. guest additions isn't going to be mounted as ext4, it's a cdrom file system. sda1 is probably root or swap. Something happened besides this, what?

Comment: It does not seem some apparent error connected to GUI. Also, I don't understand why it crashes in idle mode.

Comment: So the re-mount message is the normal message during boot process - first the root file system gets mounted read-only, then it gets re-mounted with write enabled.  The `Opts: errors=remount-ro` means the **mounting options** are "if you find severe errors, again re-mount it, but this time read-ony". That's not an error.

Comment: Your X log says that it correctly finds the VMWARE driver, runs it in 800x600 mode, but cannot initialize any of the various extensions. The `(EE) No surface to present from.` likely means that your desktop is using something that expects to have at least some of those extensions running. So either try to setup everything so acceleration works (you may have to install some libraries), or use something as your desktop that does not depend on acceleration.

Comment: And none of this happens "suddenly", you probably installed or de-installed something on your system, or you changed the setup of your VM (e.g., hardware assigned to it) If you remember what you did (you can also look up changes to the Debian installation in the logs), that may also give a clue as to what goes wrong now.

Comment: Could something have changed in your BIOS?  Make sure virtualization is enabled there (Might be called VT-x or AMD-V).  What is your host OS?

Comment: Also, which display manager are you using?  GDM usually starts on TTY2 so you might simply be in the wrong TTY. Try HOST+F2.

Answer (score 0):

You maybe out of disk space, check that out, maybe the `/var/log` folder filled your drive.
You can also test with a liveCD the disk to make sure the file-system is not damaged `fsck.ext4`.

Answer (score -2):

This can happen due to various reasons, updating your system incorrectly being one of them.
Last time I faced this issue, I manually uninstalled and installed the python and it worked for me.
can you try the following:

```
sudo apt remove python

sudo apt install python
```

if you have more than one version of python installed then you might need to use `python2` or `python2.7` in the above command so that the terminal doesn't contradict with the version.

Make sure you are rebooting the system correctly after you perform the above steps.